# Is CountDownTimer memory automatically freed in onFinish() method?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented 2 CountDownTimers in one activity:

First CountDownTimer:

```
my_count_downtimer1 = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        is_active1=true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    is_active1=false;

    }

}.start();


public void cancelmycountdowntimer1(){
if(my_count_downtimer!=null){
   my_count_downtimer.cancel();
   is_active1=false;
  }
}
```

Second CountDownTimer:

```
my_count_downtimer2 = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        is_active2=true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    is_active2=false;

    }

}.start();


public void cancelmycountdowntimer2(){
if(my_count_downtimer2!=null){
   my_count_downtimer2.cancel();
   is_active2=false;
  }
}
```

What I am doing to avoid memory leaks and free everything:

```
public void freeAllTimers(){
  if(is_active1){
  cancelmycountdowntimer1();
  }

  if(is_active2){
  cancelmycountdowntimer2();
  }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    freeAllTimers()
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    freeAllTimers()
}
```

Now my question is: if one timer has finished, according to my freeAllTimers() method, that timer won't be cancelled as is_active will be false, okay, but what happens with that memory? Is that memory automatically freed in onFinish() method?

In conclusion, is my implementation of CountDownTimers looking good to avoid all possible memory leaks? Thanks

UPDATED IMPLEMENTATION:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
    private long timeRemaining = 20000;
    private TextView mTextField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mTextField = findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);

        createTimer(timeRemaining);

        Button pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
                    myCountDownTimer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        Button resumeButton = findViewById(R.id.resumeButton);
        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createTimer(timeRemaining);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createTimer(long millisInFuture) {


        myCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };

        myCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            myCountDownTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it isn't freed, what do you propose to do about it?

Comment: it's obvious that if it isn't freed, a good practice should be to free it somewhere, this is why I made this question

Answer (score 1):

> Is CountDownTimer memory automatically freed

Yes. Instances are subject to garbage collection just like any other object.

> in onFinish() method?

No.  `CountDownTimer.onFinish()` is abstract.  You need to, and do, implement it.  Your implementation defines what it does.

More generally, Java is a garbage-collected language, with no mechanism to explicitly free any object.  No object will be freed while it is still strongly reachable, and an object is definitely strongly reachable while any thread is executing one of its instance methods.

`CountDownTimer` is a bit unusual, in that it engages asynchronous execution, but it is reasonable to expect that soon after its `onFinish()` method is invoked *as part of its normal lifecycle*, that execution resource will clear all its references to that `CountDownTimer` instance.  If no other references are held, then that will make it eligible for garbage collection.

I note, however, that you appear to be holding your own references to your `CountDownTimers` in variables `my_count_downtimer1` and `my_count_downtimer2`.  As long as you do, and the object to which those variables belong itself remains reachable, the `CountDownTimer`s will remain reachable, and therefore will not be subject to GC.

Comment: I don't understand. If the timer is not cancelled, there would be a memory leak exception. Then, when onFinish() is executed, why the memory won't be automatically freed? Also, please tell me if my implementation is correct

Comment: @pequeñaluna, again, **Java is a garbage collected language**.  Memory is not managed manually, and there are never any memory leaks *per se*.  Please read this whole answer carefully.  It already explains that although the timer will not be freed *in* the `onFinish()` method, it may be come eligible for collection *soon after that method returns*.  And it also explains why that might not be enough in your particular case.

Comment: Okay, I have understood. So there are two approaches in which the garbage collector will be freeing the countdowntimer. One approach is when the countdowntimer is canceled and the other is if the countdowntimer has finished, right?

Comment: No, @pequeñaluna, you still don't seem to be getting it.  The timer will become eligible for garbage collection when it is no longer reachable.  This is a matter of where references to it are held.  While the timer is running, it's going to be reachable from the thread(s) responsible for processing its ticks.  After it stops, that thread no longer factors in -- whether the timer is canceled or not, whether its `onFinish()` method was invoked during its shutdown or not -- but any other references, such as held in your object's variable's, still do.

Comment: Hi, sorry again, I have updated the code with a new CountDownTimer implementation where I also have 2 buttons that I will add that will use onPauseButtonClicked and onResumeButtonClicked. I have read again all our conversation and I think now the code I have made is looking great, could you confirm this please? Thanks you a lot ! for example if now I have understood you correctly I have added myCountDownTimer = null; in onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

A CountDownTimer's internal Handler's reference is captured by the Looper it is installed on until the CountDownTimer is cancelled or finishes on its own.

So in your example, there are two strong references being held per timer:

1. Your member variable holding the CountDownTimer.
2. The Looper's MessageQueue's reference to the CountDownTimer's internal Handler.

When your Activity finishes, your member variable reference is dropped. The CountDownTimer instance is definitely eligible for garbage collection right then if nothing is holding a reference to the Activity. Note, your CountDownTimer itself could be holding an Activity reference if it touches any of the Activity's members, as yours do by using `mTextField`.

The CountDownTimer's internal Handler will become eligible for garbage collection if the timer is cancelled or finishes on its own.

In your example, you cancel both the timers in `onDestroy()`, so there are no memory leaks. However, there's no harm in calling `cancel()` multiple times on a timer, so you don't need those `is_active` variables if that's the only reason you have them.

---

You could build a self-releasing subclass of CountDownTimer that takes a LifecycleOwner as a constructor parameter and registers to cancel itself when the associated Lifecycle is complete. ComponentActivity and AppCompatActivity are LifecycleOwners.

Comment: could you provide some official documentation where it says that there's no harm in calling cancel() multiple times on a timer ? thanks

Comment: The official documentation for the method does not warn you against doing this so it can be assumed safe. You can look at the source code to prove it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java

Comment: "You could build a self-releasing subclass of CountDownTimer that takes a LifecycleOwner as a constructor parameter and registers to cancel itself when the associated Lifecycle is complete. ComponentActivity and AppCompatActivity are LifecycleOwners." -- I have tried to make a new implementation without the need of using that, can you see it and let me know if it is looking good? Thanks

Comment: At first glance it looks ok, but there’s no need to set the variable to null in this case since the Activity should become eligible for GC right after `onDestroy()` provided you haven’t leaked a reference to the Activity itself. I think what they were getting at in the other answer would apply if your variable holding the reference were not a part of the Activity. There was no way to be sure from the code you originally shared.

Comment: In conclusion, in onDestroy() method, myCountDownTimer = null; is unnecessary as the variable holding the reference is an attribute of the activity as when the activity destroys, myCountDownTimer will be also destroyed, right?

Comment: Yes, because that’s the only reference held to the CountDownTimer, and the reference to the activity held by the OS behind the scenes is about to be dropped.